# How to use a cookie to detect if the user has already submitted the form?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm not looking for someone to do my work for me... I need help/advice.

I need to:

> Modify the form page so that when the JavaScript function has verified that all of the required fields have been filled, a cookie is added to the user's computer. If the same user attempts to fill out the form a second time, the user will be directed to a separate HTML page advising them that they have already submitted the form.

What am I doing wrong?

This is my form:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Request Form</title>


<meta name="Description" content="This webpage is for  Customer   Demographics" />
<meta name="Keywords" content="Rhonda , email, " />
<meta name="author" content="Rhonda " />
<meta name="copyright" content="Copyright 2010 Rhonda , All Rights Reserved"   />
<meta name="robots" content="all" />
<meta name="revisit-after" content="15 days" />
<meta name="rating" content="safe for kids" />

<script>

<!-- page to go to if cookie -->


go_to = "Submit.html";


num_days = -1;
function ged(noDays){
var today = new Date();
var expr = new Date(today.getTime() + noDays*24*60*60*1000);
return  expr.toGMTString();
}

function readCookie(cookieName){
var start = document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName);
if (start == -1){ 
    document.cookie = "seenit=yes; expires=" + ged(num_days);
} else {
    window.location = go_to;
}
}

readCookie("seenit");

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >


function verify() {
var themessage = "You are required to complete the following fields: ";
if (document.form.first.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " - First Name";
}
if (document.form.middle.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " -  Middle Initial";
}
if (document.form.last.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " -  Last Name";
}
if (document.form.street.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " - Street";
}
if (document.form.city.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " -  City";
}
if (document.form.state.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " -  State";
}
if (document.form.zip.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " -  Zip Code";
}
if (document.form.email.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " -  E-mail";
}
if (document.form.areacode.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " - Area Code";
}
if (document.form.telephone.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " - Telephone";
}
if (themessage == "You are required to complete the following fields: ") {
document.form.submit();
}
else {
alert(themessage);
return false;
}
} 

</script>   
</head>



<body>
<body style="background-color:lightsteelblue">


<h1>
    Welcome  customer.
    <br />
    <br />
    <br /> 
Please enter the following details in order
to be added to our preferred customer mailing list:
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
</h1>
<!--This code builds the form -->

<form  name=form method="post" action="">

<!--Personal information: -->
<form action="">
<fieldset>
<legend>Personal Information:</legend>      

<br /><br />
First Name:<input type=text name="first" size="20"> <br /><br /><br />
Middle Initial:<input type=text name="middle" size="3"><br /><br /><br />
Last Name:<input type=text name="last" size="20"> <br /><br />
<br />
</fieldset>
<br /><br />

<form action="">
<fieldset>
<legend>Address:</legend>
<!--Address:  -->
Street: <input type=text name="street" size="30"><br /><br />
City: <input type=text name="city" size="30"><br/><br />
State:<input type=text name="state" size="2"><br/><br />
Zip Code: <input type=text  name="zip" size="7"><br /><br />
<br />
</fieldset>

<br /><br />
<!--Contact Information: -->
<form action="">
<fieldset>
<legend>Contact Information:</legend>       

Email Address:<input type=text name="email"  size="25" />

<br /><br />


Area Code:<input type=text name="areacode"  size="3" /><br /><br /> 
Telephone Number:<input type=text name="telephone"  size="7" /> 
<br />
<br />
</fieldset>

<br /><br /><br />

<!--NOTES 
This part was not mandantory. I was just trying some of the extra ways of adding     input that the book discussed-->       

<form action="">
<fieldset>
<legend>Extra Credit:</legend>

<p> 
Gender:
<br />
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male<br />
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female
</p>        


<p>
How did you hear about us?
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Friend" value="Friend" /> From a friend
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Advertisement" value="Advertisement" />    Store   Advertisement
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Online" value="Online" /> From Online
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="Other" value="Other" /> Other
<br />
</p>



<p>     
How do you wish to be contacted?
<br />
<form action="">
<select name="contact">
<option value="telephone">Telephone</option>
<option value="E-mail">E-mail</option>
<option value="Snail-mail">Snail-mail</option>
</select>
<br />
<br />
</fieldset>
</p>    


</form> 
<form action=""  onSubmit="return verify()" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
<input type=reset value="Clear Form"><br>
</form>

<!--Back to top -->
<p><a href="#top">Back to Top</a></p> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a programming question. Moving to to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Tokk: ["The homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @rh0nda, please (as always) continue to follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints), state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to note is that nested `<form>` tags are not legal HTML.  You only need one form tag to wrap everything that you want to submit from before the first `<input>` to after the submit button.  Add your `onSubmit` handler to that form tag.

Additionally, your first script tag:

A) Does not have a `type="text/javascript"` attribute (which is, I believe required if your are using XHTML.)
B) Is using an HTML comment `<!-- -->` rather than a JavaScript comment `//` or `/* */`, which is probably throwing an error and killing everything that happens below it.

Fix those two things, and if it's still not working, come back and edit the question, adding more information about the errors you're seeing and what you've tried so far to fix them.  :-)